# Spider Crawls 0 pages

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to scrape all prices and models from the following page:

```html
<li class="item col-sm-4 col-xs-6" product-id="156385" itemscope  itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    .....
      <span class="product-name" itemprop="name">35/139 Tokyo</span>
    .....
        <span class="model" itemprop="model">107-0001 BEKKO2</span>
    .....                   
           <span class="price" itemprop="price" content="2349.00">2 349 KČ            </span>
    ..
</li>

<li class="item col-sm-4 col-xs-6" product-id="13456" itemscope  itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    .....
      <span class="product-name" itemprop="name">35/139 Tokyo</span>
    .....
        <span class="model" itemprop="model"> Model 3 </span>
    .....                   
           <span class="price" itemprop="price" content="2459.00">2 459 KČ            </span>
    ..
</li>
....
```

And so on, every li holds a model of this brand.

I have created a spider class for that:

```py
import scrapy

class EyreimSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "eyerim"
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'http://eyerim.cz/brand/35-139-tokyo/'
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        for models in response.css('li.item.col-sm-4.colxs-6'):  #holds all the models
            yield {
                #'product_name': models.css('span.product-name').get(),
                #'price': models.css('span.price::text').get().partition('K')[0].rstrip().replace(u'\xa0', u''),    
                'model' : models.css('span.model::text').extract(),
                'price':  models.css('span::attr(content)').extract()
            }
```

But when I run the spider there are not results:

```
Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
```

the response.css expressions work  Ihave tried them all in scrappy shell and they return results.... I am trying to figure this out from yesterday but with no success... any ideas?? suggestions??? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see your sample code. You mistyped `colxs-6` instead  of `col-xs-6` in css item selsector. 
As scrapy can't find element with class `colxs-6` `->` `EyreimSpider.parse` method can't retrieve data